# How to utilize multi-word Name Entity Recognition in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, nltk

I am trying to find multi-word name entities. I have an example input such as

```
magic johnson is the owner of l.a. lakers.
ceo kevin johnson citing issues related to covid 19 as the reason for the deal’s termination.
susan somersille johnson went to school to be an engineer, yet somehow managed to carve out a nearly 30 year career in marketing.
```

and the code I have is

```
import nltk
import re

sentence = ""

with open("test.txt", "r") as inFile:
    sentence = inFile.read()

for sent in nltk.sent_tokenize(sentence):
    for chunk in nltk.ne_chunk(nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(sent))):
        print(chunk)
        #if hasattr(chunk, 'label'):
            #print(chunk.label(), ' '.join(c[0] for c in chunk))
```

However, using this code, I get

```
('magic', 'JJ')
('johnson', 'NN')
('is', 'VBZ')
('the', 'DT')
('owner', 'NN')
('of', 'IN')
(ORGANIZATION l.a./JJ)
('lakers', 'NNS')
('.', '.')
('ceo', 'NN')
('kevin', 'VBZ')
('johnson', 'JJ')
('citing', 'VBG')
('issues', 'NNS')
('related', 'VBN')
('to', 'TO')
('covid', 'VB')
('19', 'CD')
('as', 'IN')
('the', 'DT')
('reason', 'NN')
('for', 'IN')
('the', 'DT')
('deal', 'NN')
('’', 'NNP')
('s', 'NN')
('termination', 'NN')
('.', '.')
('susan', 'JJ')
('somersille', 'NN')
('johnson', 'NN')
```

Which is not what I want to accomplish.
How do I tweak this code, so that I get

```
magic johnson
l.a. lakers
kevin johnson
```

etc., as one entity?